# Refresh the canvas only for certain brushes

Tags: c#, graphics, drawing

I'm trying to graph some circles and lines etc but I only want some lines to refresh on the canvas and the others not to, is there any way around this?

For example the mypen, mypen2 and mypen3, I want them to refresh on canvas but the graphics "g" a little further down I don't want to refresh, I want all the instances to show. How do I do this? Here is my code

```
private void drawlines()
{
    canvas.Refresh();
    int j = Int32.Parse(ivalue.Text);

    float position1 = canvas.Width / 2;
    float position2 = canvas.Height / 2;

    float XX = (float)(Math.Round(position1 + Math.Sin(DegreeToRadian(j)) * 100));
    float XY = (float)(Math.Round(position2 - Math.Cos(DegreeToRadian(j)) * 100));
    float X2 = (position1 + XX);

    float XY2 = XY;

    System.Drawing.Pen myPen;
    System.Drawing.Pen myPen2;
    System.Drawing.Pen myPen3;
    System.Drawing.Pen myPen4;

    myPen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
    myPen2 = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Blue);
    myPen3 = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
    myPen4 = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Green);
    System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics = canvas.CreateGraphics();
    formGraphics.DrawRectangle(myPen,XX, XY,3,3);
    formGraphics.DrawRectangle(myPen2, canvas.Width / 2, XY, 3, 3);
    formGraphics.DrawRectangle(myPen3, position1, position2, 3, 3);
    formGraphics.DrawRectangle(myPen4, position1, XY2, 3, 3);
    label1.Text = Convert.ToString(XY);
    label1.Refresh();

    listBox1.Items.Clear();

    listBox1.Items.Add("XX=[" + XX + "] XY=[" + XY + "]");
} 


private void Go_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 360; i = i + 1)
    {
        drawlines();
        int linearm = (canvas.Width / 2) - i;

        ivalue.Text = Convert.ToString(i);
        ivalue.Refresh();
        int testx = Int32.Parse(label1.Text);

        Graphics g;
        g = canvas.CreateGraphics();
        Pen p;
        Rectangle r;
        p = new Pen(Brushes.Green);
        r = new Rectangle(linearm,testx, 1, 1);

        g.DrawRectangle(p, r);

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using winforms? If so you need to change your code to work like this:

To be persistant everything need to be drawin in the `Paint` event and using its `e.Graphics` object. (This is the **Golden Rule**! Corollary: Never use `System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics = canvas.CreateGraphics();`)

Everything you want to be drawn must be stored in `Lists` of classes, sufficient to hold all info you need.

If you were to draw only `Rectangles` in only one pen a `List<Rectangle>` would be enough, but for other shapes and pens you will want to create a `class` to hold those data.

Now you can:

- Draw them all in the `Paint` event, iterating the `List<your DrawItemClass>`
- Remove or set inactive those items in the List you don't want to be drawn any longer..